# C# datagridview rows sum if

Tags: datagridview, sum, where-clause

how to sum datagridview values where txtbox value = datagridview value ?
This is my code. now does not summarize, but only takes the last value.

```
if (row.Cells["SSCC"].Value.ToString() == txt_naujas_sscc.Text)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                //for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                //{
                sum = sum + int.Parse(row.Cells["QuantityDespatched"].Value.ToString());
                txt_sscc_pre_ska.Text = sum.ToString();
                //}
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
   if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SSCC"].Value.ToString() == txt_naujas_sscc.Text) {
   sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["QuantityDespatched].Value);
   }
}
txt_sscc_pre_ska.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: no work :( counts the entire column, but only specific lines are needed, where the value from txtbox if (row.Cells["SSCC"].Value.ToString() == txt_naujas_sscc.Text)

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that requirement. Have changed answer accordingly.